# Keep a division active after form submit using localStorage

Tags: javascript, php, forms, post

I have an issue with keeping a division active after submitting a form using AJAX. My scenario is that I have a search bar, which can take multiple types of input (Name, ID, category, etc.). Then, I have a filter bar which is basically an advanced search, it practically does the same thing but has more options like separate fields for Name, ID, Category, price range, etc. these are some important terms,

1. ID: product ID
2. Name: Product name
3. SPL_CD: Special code assigned to every product
4. ALT_NM2: Alternate name/Description
5. costStart/costEnd: range search for all products whose cost price is between the range
6. sellStart/sellEnd: range search for all products whose selling price is between the range
7. cname: category of the product
8. gname: group the product is classified under the category

I don't care much for the CSS, **but the point is that, anyone using this page at client end needs to see the values inserted in the filter dropdown i.e. keeping the filter drop down visible even on page reload.** After submitting the form, my entire page reloads. This makes the dropdown go hidden again. I am bad at AJAX so I do not know how to do it, any help would be appreciated.

This is the working fiddle (ignore the lack of CSS, as it is all majorly defined under a different file based on MVC approach)- [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/retrop5/45jgv6qs/33/)
This fiddle as well, does not support keeping the division active after the form is submitted, so I am trying to switch to AJAX.

This is what my AJAX approach is, but it keeps displaying a blank instead of the table and its data.

```
$("#searchButton").click(function() {
        var params = {
            searchKeyword: $("#searchKeyword").val()
        };
        var form = $("#searchArea");
        var url = form.attr("action")+"?"+$.param(params);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            colModel:[
                {label:'ProductID', name:'ITM_CD',classes:'ITM_CD', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Name', name:'ITM_NM',classes:'ITM_NM',width:100, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Alt.name', name:'ITM_ALT_NM2',classes:'ITM_ALT_NM2', width:100, align:"center", sorttype:"string"},
                {label:'Special code', name:'SPL_CD',classes:'SPL_CD', width:50, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Sort Order', name:'SORDER',classes:'SORDER', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Talent Points', name:'TPOINTS',classes:'TPOINTS', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Selling price', name:'SPRICE',classes:'SPRICE', width:30, align:"right", sorttype:"string"},
                {label:'Cost price', name:'CPRICE',classes:'CPRICE', width:30, align:"right", sorttype:"string"},
                {label: 'Category Name', name:'CNAME', classes: 'CNAME', width: 30, align: "right", sorttype:"string"},
                {label: 'Group name', name:'GNAME', classes: 'GNAME', width: 30, align: "right", sorttype:"string"}
        ],
        });
    });
    $("#searchButton").click(function() {
        var params = {
          searchKeyword: $("#searchKeyword").val(),
            IDKeyword: $("#IDKeyword").val(),
            NMKeyword: $("#NMKeyword").val(),
            NM2Keyword: $("#NM2Keyword").val(),
            SCKeyword: $("#SCKeyword").val(),
            costStartKeyword: $("#costStartKeyword").val(),
            costEndKeyword: $("#costEndKeyword").val(),
            sellStartKeyword: $("#sellStartKeyword").val(),
            sellEndKeyword: $("#sellEndKeyword").val(),
            cnameKeyword: $("#cnameKeyword").val(),
            gnameKeyword: $("#gnameKeyword").val()
        };
        var form = $("#dropDownFilter");
        var url = form.attr("action")+"?"+$.param(params);
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            colModel:[
                {label:'ProductID', name:'ITM_CD',classes:'ITM_CD', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Name', name:'ITM_NM',classes:'ITM_NM',width:100, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Alt.name', name:'ITM_ALT_NM2',classes:'ITM_ALT_NM2', width:100, align:"center", sorttype:"string"},
                {label:'Special code', name:'SPL_CD',classes:'SPL_CD', width:50, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Sort Order', name:'SORDER',classes:'SORDER', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Talent Points', name:'TPOINTS',classes:'TPOINTS', width:40, align:"center", sorttype:"int"},
                {label:'Selling price', name:'SPRICE',classes:'SPRICE', width:30, align:"right", sorttype:"string"},
                {label:'Cost price', name:'CPRICE',classes:'CPRICE', width:30, align:"right", sorttype:"string"},
                {label: 'Category Name', name:'CNAME', classes: 'CNAME', width: 30, align: "right", sorttype:"string"},
                {label: 'Group name', name:'GNAME', classes: 'GNAME', width: 30, align: "right", sorttype:"string"}
        ],
        });
    });
});
```

The HTML and the CSS is the same as the Fiddle.

### Edit 1: Tried the Local Storage

```
$("#filterSearchButton").on("click", function(){
        localStorage.setItem("style", $("#dropDownFilter").css("display", "none"));
    });
    if (localStorage.getItem("style") === null) {
        localStorage.setItem("style", $("#dropDownFilter").css("display", "flex"));
    } else {
        $("#dropDownFilter").css("display", "flex");
    }
});
```

**Problem: The dropdown displays on first reload too, need to avoid that.**

Comment: Can you try setitem and get item

window.localStorage.setItem("PortalLoginApp.userName", username);

var userName = window.localStorage.getItem("PortalLoginApp.userName");

Comment: It will store your ajax last response.

Comment: I am not exactly sure how to use local storage or session storage, could you share a code block? Mean while, I'll try what you said.

Comment: Do you have any variable which you want to show after ajax call . and have to use that variable after page reload too ?

Comment: Hey, I tried the localStorage approach, it works up to some extent. The dropDown is visible, but I want it to be hidden on opening the page for the first time, this does not by default stay hidden on first reload.

Comment: I have added the code for localstorage as an edit in the question itself

Comment: I have an entire jqGrid to show after the ajax call, but it is automatic and there is no other variable that I have to show.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Use localstorage **setItem** and **getItem** to store ajax last respone.

```
window.localStorage.setItem("variable", variable);

var getItem = window.localStorage.getItem("variable");
```

also when You want to **remove** the setItem you can remove it too.

```
window.localStorage.removeItem('variable');
```

Comment: Is there any way, the remove item can be specifically used for the first time loading into a page?

Comment: When your project will run getitem will not have any assigned value . 
after the ajax call it will set the value in localstorage. 
so you just have to remove the item from localstorage when you do some other ajax call or when you go back to home page.

Comment: In my edit 1, I added the condition wherein which if the division is not displayed i.e. "display: none", then don't show the division style stored by the localStorage. This should disable the localStorage from processing it's contents. If the division is displayed then it will show. It is more of a cheap trick, if clients want to use filter based search they will have to open the filter bar, which means display gets updated to flex. It will permit the localStorage to show it again. But it is not behaving the way it is supposed to. it shows the division even though it is the first reload.

Comment: Also, I am using jqGrid without the AJAX because I found out the parameters and the constraints were not defined with AJAX format and redoing it would take a lot of time.

Comment: I have updated the code in the fiddle file too, please check.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @bhavik I have tried the approach using localStorage and it worked, for doing the same thing with avoiding the division to open on page reload I simply changed the way the form was being submitted. instead of an if statement I simply said,

```
$(document).on("click", "#report tr", function(){
        parent.onSearched($("#report").getRowData($(this).attr("value")));
});
```